# Java HTML file load from Eclipse folder

Tags: java, swing, url, jeditorpane, fileinputstream

I am encountering a problem loading an HTML file in an editor pane and displaying it. The code I am using is:

```
window_pane = new JEditorPane("file:///assets/www/index.html");
```

But that just gave some errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: \assets\www\index.html (Het systeem kan het opgegeven pad niet vinden)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JEditorPane.getStream(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JEditorPane.setPage(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JEditorPane.setPage(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JEditorPane.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at nl.xedus.battlex.java.WebBrowser.<init>(WebBrowser.java:33)
    at nl.xedus.battlex.java.WebBrowser.main(WebBrowser.java:72)
```

ScreenShot:

[image]

Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like a relative path in your file URL. You need to use an absolute path. For resources bundled with your application you can get a URL like this:

```
final String resourcePath = "foobar.html";
URL resourceURL = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(resourcePath);
JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane(resourceURL);
```

This assumes that there is an HTML file named 'foobar.html' at the root of your classpath. Extend the pseudocode to serve your needs.

Comment: Tried things like assets/www/index.html but that faild too

Comment: @Dallox - that is also a relative URL. For Unix an absolute path would start with a `/` or `/home` (or `/Users` on Mac). For Windows it would start with a drive letter like `C:\`.

Comment: But the html file needs to be compiled in the jar (Using eclipse) So how can i give an absolute path there

Comment: @Dallox - You didn't mention that in your original question. See edits to my answer.

Comment: Thanks the code works when i put the index.html in the src folder, guess ill keep my html files there, thanks alot :D